# MSVC Linker option debug:fastlink causing program execution slowdown

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, linker, visual-studio-2017

When passing the linker switch debug:fastlink to Visual studio's linker (version 14.11.25547 - VS 2017 update 15.5) I always get a 5-7 second delay in my program execution when trying to run it inside VS debugger. I'm assuming the debug:fastlink option is the issue since when I remove it, everything works alright. Also, no change occurs if I try the option debug:full. It seems in order for VS debugger to hit my breakpoints the linker needs to be passed one of these options. Is anyone else having this issue? And is there any workout/solution for this? Just in case here is my build.bat file:

```
@echo off

set CompilerFlags= -DHANDMADE_SLOW_BUILD=1 -DHANDMADE_DEVELOPER_BUILD=1 -MT -Gm- -Z7 -nologo -Oi -Od -WX -W3 -GR -EHa-

set IncludePaths="w:\handmade\third party\sdl\include"

set LibraryPaths=/LIBPATH:"w:\handmade\third party\sdl\lib\x64"
set Libraries="SDL2.lib" "SDL2main.lib"
REM debug:fastlink/full options seem to slow the initial runtime of the app when trying to run in the debugger.
set LinkerFlags=-subsystem:CONSOLE -machine:x64 -incremental:no -nologo debug:fastlink -opt:ref

IF NOT EXIST build mkdir build
pushd build

REM 32-bit build
REM cl %CommonCompilerFlags% ..\handmade\code\win32_handmade.cpp /link -subsystem:windows,5.1 %CommonLinkerFlags%

REM 64-bit build
cl /c %CompilerFlags% -I %IncludePaths% w:\handmade\source\win32_handmade.cpp 
link %LinkerFlags% -out:win32_handmade.exe ../build/win32_handmade.obj %Libraries% %LibraryPaths%
copy /y  "w:\handmade\third party\sdl\lib\x64\SDL2.dll" "w:\handmade\build"
popd
```

Comment: Have you seen this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/10/05/faster-c-build-cycle-in-vs-15-with-debugfastlink/ they say "There is a small increase in time taken for first name lookup related debugging actions (like function/data lookup by name for expression evaluation in watch windows) but it’s only noticeable for very large binaries (>50 Mb)" maybe you could try to comment that or also https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/67777/initializing-symbol-search-table-takes-a-long-time.html

Comment: Well currently my exe is only 123 kb so don't think that should cause any issues but I will also try and comment on those sites as well to see if anything can be done.

Comment: This suggests it is a bug : "Hi, Thank you for reporting this /fastlink problem. We are investigating and working on a solution and expect to mitigate the slowness in upcoming 15.6 release." (from the last page Simon linked to)

Comment: Ya, it looks like it. Pretty annoying.